# "Всероссийский Некрасовский семинар" — со строчной или с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

Помогите правильно написать:

*Всероссийский Некрасовский семинар* или *всероссийский Некрасовский семинар.*

"Некрасовский", считаю, надо с прописной буквы, так как семинар - в память о Некрасове, а как быть со "всероссийский"?

И еще: аббревиатура оош (основная образовательная школа) - со строчной или с прописной буквы, то есть ООШ.

Как правильно, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: _Верьясова: "Большая буква **или** прописная"_. ===  А почему "или"? Большая -- она и  есть прописная. Правильно было бы так:  _"Большая буква или маленькая?"_  Или так:  _"Прописная буква или строчная?"_

Answer (score 6):

1) Правильно: **Всероссийский Некрасовский семинар**

**Розенталь:**  Имена прилагательные на -ский, входящие в состав названий, имеющих значение ‘имени или памяти такого-то’, пишутся с прописной буквы: Булгаковские вечера, Ломоносовские чтения. [Прилагательные и наречия, образованные от индивидуальных названий | Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=16#pp16)

**Всероссийский** - первое слово в названии (в имени собственном)

Сравнить: Вечер проходил в **толстовской** усадьбе «Хамовники» (нарицательное значение).

2) **Пример ООШ:**

МБОУ ООШ с.Топлое

Муниципальное бюджетное общеобразовательное учреждение  основная общеобразовательная школа с. Топлое

Comment: Всероссийский Некрасовский семинар - причина несколько иная.Это названия съездов и конгрессов всегда пишутся с большой буквы, а что касается культурных и спортивных мероприятий, первое слово пишется с большой буквы, если они имеют общегосударственное или международное значение, т.е. слова Всероссийский и Международный всегда с прописной, а вот "городской Некрасовский семинар " - первое слово с маленькой, оно не входит в название, это обозначение уровня. А аббревиатуры учебных заведений - официальное название, поэтому с большой все буквы.